# Queue implementation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, queue

I'm creating a program to create a queue and add,delete and display elements.
For this I create a list, then take input from users and append the same number of 0s and then proceed normally. The problem arises that the value of rear and front does not change and remains constant which leads to it not displaying and also not filling up.

How can I fix this.

```
l=[]
global front
global rear
front=-1
rear=-1
print("Enter the number of elements ")
maxsize=int(input())
i=0
q=0
for q in range(0,maxsize):       #for creating an array with user input number of 0s
    l.append(0)

def isFull():
    if(rear==maxsize):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def isEmpty():
    if(front==-1 and rear==-1):
        return 1
    elif(front==rear):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def enqueue(n):
    if(isEmpty()==1):
        front=0
        rear=0
        l[rear]=n
        rear=rear+1
    else:
        l[rear]=n
        rear=rear+1

def dequeue():
    if(isEmpty()==1):
        return 1
    else:
        front=front+1

while(i==0):
    print("Add an element ?(0) \nDelete an element?(1) \nDisplay the 
elements?(2)\n")
    a=int(input())
    if(a==0):
        if(isFull()==1):
            print("Queue is full")
        else:
            b=int(input())
            enqueue(b)
    if(a==1):
        dequeue()
    if(a==2):
        for c in range(front,rear):
            print(l[c])
```

Comment: Do you have a homework assignment to create a queue, or do you just need a queue for some other task? If the latter, just use `collections.deque`, which already has methods you can use to efficiently add elements to one end and remove elements from the other.

Comment: It is an assignment where I have to use the standard functions

Comment: @NamanSood, did I answer your question?

Comment: @MayankMehtani yes thank's a lot it solved all of my errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redeclare the global variables (front,rear in this case) at the start of any methods using them. Like this

```
def enqueue(n):
    global front
    global rear
    if(isEmpty()==1):
        front=0
        rear=0
        l[rear]=n
        rear=rear+1
    else:
        l[rear]=n
        rear=rear+1
```